# JPA saveAll faster and more reliable then save with large inserts

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I recently made an app that took data from one database (legacy) and put it into another (new dev DB). What I found perplexing was `save` didn't always work but `saveAndFlush` did. The `legacy` database was in one transaction `select` and the new database was in another `deleteAll` and `save`.

The app was very very slow with `saveAndFlush` and understandable but `save` was not much better. Then I decided to use `saveAll` but the idea of creating a huge list for each table didn't set well with me. So I tried to invoke garage collection like so:

```
 productRepository.saveAll(productList);

 productList.clear();
 productList = null;
 System.gc();
```

I then added `jdbc.batch_size` to `application.properties`

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=info
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true
```

What took two hours to run before was now at 5 minutes - huge performance gain.

Now I am confused what is going on. What I read is it is "updating and cleaing the session in regular intervals". But the `delete` and `saveAll` are in one transaction - therefore it doesn't make sense to me.

So to be clear why two questions are:

1) Why doesn't `save` always work but `saveAndFlush` will?

2) Having 50 tables with 20,000 rows each and each table creates a list, then `saveAll`, list is cleared and suggested for garbage collection. Adding the above to `application.properties` resulted in a blazingly fast app when compared to approach `#1`. Why? What is hibernate doing? Updating and clearing the session in regular intervals?

What I thought was happening is the first layer cache held the delete and inserts and later committed and hopefully flushed. Apparently I am wrong or at least not completely correct.

[JPA batch inserts with Hibernate & Spring Data](https://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/)

Comment: These are two questions. Please ask only one question per posting. The question about `save` vs `saveAndFlush` (vs `saveAll` from the title) needs more detail. What does "not working" mean? Silent failure to save? An exception? Did the computer crash? The question about batching while vague has been answered many times on this site in on form or the other.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between **save** and **saveAndFlush** lies in the way they handle transactions and persisting data to the database. In the case of save, the data is saved to the database, but it might not be immediately flushed to the database. The actual flushing may occur later when the current transaction is committed, or when the persistence context is flushed. On the other hand, **saveAndFlush** immediately persists the data to the database and flushes the changes. This means that the data is guaranteed to be saved in the database before the method call returns.

The significant performance gain you observed when using **saveAll** and garbage collection, along with the batch size configuration, can be attributed to Hibernate's batching mechanism. When you use **saveAll**, Hibernate optimizes the insert operations by batching multiple inserts together, reducing the number of database round-trips and improving performance. The **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size** property you configured specifies the number of statements that will be sent to the database in a batch when executing an **INSERT or UPDATE** operation. This batching approach is more efficient than individual inserts for each entity, especially when dealing with a large number of entities.

By explicitly clearing the productList and invoking garbage collection, you are freeing up memory resources, which can further improve performance, especially in situations with limited memory or when processing large amounts of data.

In summary, the improvements you observed in performance are due to a combination of factors:

Using **saveAll** allows for batch processing, reducing the number of database round-trips.

Configuring the **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property** optimizes insert and update operations by batching them together.
Clearing the **productList** and invoking garbage collection frees up memory resources.

Overall, these optimizations lead to better performance and a more efficient use of resources when processing large datasets in your application.